# Functions with Fourier support in $[0,\infty)$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

The Paley-Wiener space is given by class of functions $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ with the property that
$$
\hat f(\xi) = 0, \quad |\xi| > \tfrac{1}{2}, \quad \hat f(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)e^{-2\pi i x \xi} dx
$$
Hence, this class consists of all functions with compact support in $[-0.5,0.5]$ in Fourier space. Now let $H$ be the class of functions which have Fourier support in a half-space, say $[0,\infty)$. Does this class have a special name or is it studied somewhere? I couldn't find much on google.

Comment: This is not the specification of the Paley-Wiener space that I've heard. What I've heard is that it consists of Fourier transforms of compactly-supported smooth functions. So, yes, translating and dilating smooth functions on a fixed interval gives that, etc., ... Beyond that (non-trivial?) quibble, have you searched on "Hardy space(s)" and such?